# Do Muggle-borns produce magical children?

Tags: harry-potter

Do Muggle-borns in the Harry Potter universe produce magical children?

Specifically just to enumerate the situations:

- If they marry a Pure-blood
- If they marry another Muggle-born
- If they marry a Muggle

What are the 'genetic rules' for heritability of magic in general?

Comment: * *cough* * **Harry Potter** * *cough* *.

Comment: From [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/157716): "Muggleborns will have a witch or wizard somewhere on their family tree, in some cases many, many generations back. The gene re-surfaces in some unexpected places." So having the gene so close to you in the family tree likely means that you're going to be a wizard.

Comment: Welcome to SFF! This is a nice first question (have my upvote). However, it would appear your question has been asked before, this is not a bad thing! Keep up the good questions!